# Defined Argument Doesn't seem to Fire

Tags: python

Please mind I am very new to the Python world.

I've been looking for an answer to this online and can't seem to find the right solution, based on my understanding I feel the logic is correct. In the end, though my results are just not there.

I am compiling with Idle.

Point of the solution: Is to take a string value of Kilometers from the console. Then convert it to Miles, then output the string.

Seems simple but debugging the below code over and over again I cannot seem to figure out why after I enter my kilometer number the print with the conversion value never displays.

```
def main(distanceMile=None):
# Declare and initialize variables
# string called distancekilo
distanceKilo = ""
# distancemile = ""
# conversion = 0.6214

# Introduction       
print("Welcome to the distance converter \n")

# Prompt for distance in Kilometers
distanceKilo = input("Enter distance in Kilometers: ")

# Default Argument
def calcConvert(value):
    conversion = 0.6214
    distanceMile = int(value) * conversion
return distanceMile

calcConvert(distanceKilo)
print("That distance in miles is ", distanceMile)
```

I would simply like to know where I am going wrong here?

Comment: If you've input the code exactly as you pasted it here, then I suspect you're getting an exception. If so, then can you please post that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has three main bugs. One is the indentation at the end of `calcConvert` (`return` should be indented). Another is that the `main` definition at the top doesn't seem to do anything. Another is that you want to save `calcConvert(distanceKilo)` to a variable. This code works:

```
# Introduction
print("Welcome to the distance converter \n")

# Prompt for distance in Kilometers
distanceKilo = input("Enter distance in Kilometers: ")

# Default Argument
def calcConvert(value):
    conversion = 0.6214
    distanceMile = int(value) * conversion
    return distanceMile

distanceMile = calcConvert(distanceKilo)
print("That distance in miles is ", distanceMile)
```

If you're new to Python, I would suggest also reading some posts and articles about the way people normally style code (like `calc_convert` vs `calcConvert`) in Python :) It's not entirely necessary, but it makes it easier for other Python users to read your code.

Comment: I keep getting this error now:  distanceMile = calc_convert(distanceKilo)
NameError: name 'distanceKilo' is not defined

Comment: though i am declaring it in the beginning

Comment: Try copy-pasting the code exactly as I have it written. That code runs fine for me.